# OpenLdap: mdb log clean up

Tags: ldap, openldap

We are migrating from OpenLDAP 2.4.44 which had HDB as a database to OpenLDAP 2.6.3 which now has MDB as a database.

In older version to cleanup DB logs we used **olcDbConfig** attribute with value *"set_flags DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE"* for dn="olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config", but in newer version this attribute seems to be not valid.

My question is: How log autoremoval implemented in 2.6.3 version of OpenLDAP? How it is configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no log autoremoval because there are no logs.

LMDB is *not* a variant of Berkeley DB like `hdb` was; it's a new database with a completely different architecture, and it has been designed to not require a transaction log or a WAL. If you look in your database directory, you won't find any files that need to be removed.